# Power Consumption for multiplying two 64 bit numbers

Tags: multiplication, energy

Can anyone help me to find the power consumed in an ( i7-6700 CPU@3.4 GHz, 4 cores, 8 logical processors) while multiplying two 64 bit numbers and adding two 64 bit numbers?

Is there any specific document/link where I can find that ?

Also what is the process to compute the number of clock cycles it takes for multiplying two 64 bit numbers?  I used rdtsc subroutine to get the time stamp before and after the multiplication, and then subtract them. Is it the correct way to do ? Please advise!

Thanks